# how to know Return type inferred in scala

Tags: scala

```
val a=10; val b=if(a==5) println("hello") else (1,"hi")
```

What will be return type inferred in this case? And How?

Comment: Paste it in a REPL, it will be `Any` probably.

Comment: This is what I see when I paste this into an `sbt console` I had open:

```
scala> val a=10; val b=if(a==5) println("hello") else (1,"hi")

val a: Int = 10

val b: Matchable = (1,hi)

```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're asking for the type of `b`, which in this case is `Any`.

```scala
if (a == 5) println("hello") else (1, "hi")
```

gets typed as follows:

- For an `if` expression, the type is the least upper bound of the two possible branches: if the consequent expression (`println("hello")` in this case) has type `A` and the alternative expression (`(1, "hi")`) has type `B`, then it is the type `C` such that `A` and `B` are both non-strict subtypes of `C` and there is no type `D` which is a strict subtype of `C` where `A` and `B` are non-strict subtypes of `D` (non-strict means that we can consider a type to be a subtype of itself; strict means we can't).
- The type of `println("hello")` is `Unit`
- The type of `(1, "hi")` is a `Tuple2[Int, String]`
- `Unit`'s supertypes are `AnyVal` and `Any`
- `Tuple2`'s supertypes are `Serializable`, `Product2[Int, String]`, `Product`, `Equals`, `AnyRef`, and `Any` (technically, `Product2`'s and `Tuple2`'s covariance means that there are some more supertypes (e.g. `Tuple2[AnyVal, String]`, `Tuple2[Int, AnyRef]`, `Tuple2[Any, Any]`), but those don't end up being relevant here)
- The least-upper-bound is therefore `Any`, so the type of the `if` expression and thus of `b` is `Any`

You can demonstrate this in a REPL, e.g. `sbt console`

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val a=10; val b=if(a==5) println("hello") else (1,"hi")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

a: Int = 10
b: Any = (1,hi)
```

Note that even though the predicate `a == 5` will never be `true` and thus the consequent branch will never be taken, the typer does not take that into account.

Note also that if you had a method with that body:

```scala
def someMethod = {
  val a = 10
  val b = if(a==5) println("hello") else (1,"hi")
}
```

The result type of that method would be `Unit`, because the result type is the type of the last expression in the method and an assignment (being a side-effect) has the type `Unit`.

Comment: That's in Scala 2, btw.  3 might have a slightly different hierarchy.